# Call a method inside the Order part of a LINQ query

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to order result query by calculate distance of two point in my code like below:

```
users = await db.tblUsers.Where(x => x.tblUserRoles.Any(a => a.RoleID == (int)RoleEnum.BranchUser) && x.tblBranchUsers.Any(b => b.tblBranchUserCityServices.Any(c => c.BranchUserID == b.BranchUserID && c.CityID == ticket.CityID_Effective && c.IsEnable) && b.IsEnable))
                .OrderBy(a => a.tblBranchUsers.Select(b => b.CountInService).FirstOrDefault())
                .OrderBy(a => a.tblBranchUsers.Select(b => b.AverageServiceTime).FirstOrDefault())
                .OrderBy(a => a.tblBranchUsers.Select(b => GeneralMethods.GetDistanceFromLatLonInKm(double.Parse(ticket.EffectiveLatitude), double.Parse(ticket.EffectiveLongitude), b.LastLatitude == null ? double.Parse(ticket.EffectiveLatitude) : double.Parse(b.LastLatitude.ToString()), b.LastLongitude == null ? double.Parse(ticket.EffectiveLongitude) : double.Parse(b.LastLongitude.ToString()))).FirstOrDefault())
                .OrderByDescending(a => a.tblBranchUsers.OrderBy(b => b.AveragePoint).FirstOrDefault())
                .ToListAsync();
```

but It throw this Error:

> linq to entities does not recognize the method and this method cannot be translated into a store

I use GetDistanceFromLatLonInKm Method for measure distance, but not work.
Please help me, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using sql server, if you want the server to do the distance calc, you'll either have to:

- reimplement GetDistanceFromLatLonInKm in [basic commands that EF can translate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/functions) - see numeric functions section,
- implement it as a user defined function and [have EF call it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping) (which could use your .net code embedded in sqlserver),
- use an [sql raw query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) in (part of) your EF query (queries can be mixed raw sql and c# expressions so long as the raw query produces a resultset that is type compatible with the c# type), and this might be particularly helpful if you're leveraging SQLS' built in geographical support
- download all the data and get c# to do the filter (last resort)

It's probably also worth mentioning that sqlserver has a lot of geographical understanding and [an entire suite of functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-data-types-overview?view=sql-server-ver15) dedicated to working out distances between points on a globe and whether points/polygons overlap other polygons. If you have all your latlongs stored as geography Point types, then ordering by distance from some point x is as simple as an sql like `...ORDER BY latLonPointColumn.STDistance(@pointx)`. If you work with them, a few tips:

- use the same SRID, probably 4326, when you create them
- points are created with lat, long in that order
- polygons are parsed from text in lon,lat order, points should be specified counter-clockwise and start and end point should be the same
- spatial functions are .net based and hence case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

It's just as it says - when entity framework is translating your LINQ query into SQL, it can use only SQL commands.

If you want to execute your method in `OrderBy`, you'll have to grab the data from the database first, and then order it client-side.

Also, you probably want to use `ThenBy` method after the first `OrderBy`.